# AngularJS push value of input to array and than display it

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a const = info ['here is my info which I display using ng-repeat'];
Then, I have an input and button save.
So, how can I on click button, save push value that I typed inside input to display it after?

app.html

```
<body ng-app="postsWall">
    <div ng-controller="feedsListController">
        <h1>POSTS WALL</h1>
        <label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search by title..." ng-model="searchText">      
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="feed in feeds | filter:searchText">
                <span>{{ feed.author }}</span>
                <h3>{{ feed.title }}</h3>
                <p>{{ feed.text }}</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </label>
    <div ng-show="newPostForm">
        <label>
            <input type="text">
            <input type="text">
            <button ng-click="addPost">Save</button>
            <button>Cancel</button>
        </label>
    </div>`enter code here`
    <button ng-click="showFunc()">Add new post</button>
    </div>
```

app.controller.js

```
const postsWall = angular.module('postsWall', []);

postsWall.controller('feedsListController', function feedsListController($scope) {
    $scope.feeds = info;
    $scope.newPostForm = false;
    $scope.showFunc = function(){
        $scope.newPostForm = !$scope.newPostForm;
    }
    $scope.addPost = function(){

    }
})
```

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Comment: Please post some relevant code to help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

at first add a object for new feed and then push it to feeds array in addPost() function

```
postsWall.controller('feedsListController', function feedsListController($scope) {
$scope.newFeed = {};
$scope.feeds = info;
$scope.newPostForm = false;
$scope.showFunc = function () {
    $scope.newPostForm = !$scope.newPostForm;
}
$scope.addPost = function () {
    if ($scope.newFeed!=null) {
        $scope.feeds.push($scope.newFeed);
        $scope.newFeed = {};
    }
}
}
```

in html code you have to bind input values to new object

```
<body ng-app="postsWall">
    <div ng-controller="feedsListController">
        <h1>POSTS WALL</h1>
        <label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search by title..." ng-model="searchText">      
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="feed in feeds | filter:searchText">
                <span>{{ feed.author }}</span>
                <h3>{{ feed.title }}</h3>
                <p>{{ feed.text }}</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </label>
    <div ng-show="newPostForm">
        <label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="newFeed.title">
            <input type="text" ng-model="newFeed.text">
            <button ng-click="addPost">Save</button>
            <button>Cancel</button>
        </label>
    </div>`enter code here`
    <button ng-click="showFunc()">Add new post</button>
    </div>
```